# Plotting XYZ On a Site Map

Tags: r

I have the xyz coordinates of samples I collected on a site map. I want to plot a heat map of the samples on the site map for visualization purposes. Can anyone point to me which package(s) in R will help me do this?

Comment: Are the coordinates measured in standard latitude and longitude?

Comment: Yes the coordinates are in standard latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 0):

Try plotly, https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/
It allows you to create interactive plots, which you can pan, zoom and rotate

I have an example - https://jpvoisey.github.io/volcano/volcano.html

```
library(datasets)
library(plotly)
data("volcano")
plot_ly(x = row(volcano) * 10, y = col(volcano) * 10, z = volcano * 10,  type = "surface") %>%
layout(title = "Topographic map of Maunga Whau", showlegend = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I will try and get back to you with any feedback.